# Issue converting bootstrap to android app using Android Studio 1.4

Tags: android, twitter-bootstrap

I guess I'm having a brain fart but I am trying to convert this simple Bootstrap design to a Android mobile app. The error I am getting on the phone is file not found for index.html. I created a directory called car, under src/res, and moved the Bootstrap folders and index.html under that directory.

I am sure the file route is wrong but I have tried different ways with no success. Any idea would be helpful.

```
    package com.example.grady.bootstraptoandroidapp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView webView;
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/car/index.html");
    }
}
```

Comment: post your stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, I needed to create an assets directory and the put the files in that. Working fine now.